# Pandas Groupby then cumulative percentage of the groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

So my Dataset looks like this, I want to group my dataset by TSI column first and then find cum% of ONS for each grouped TSI

| F TSI | F ONS | Cum%ONS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1020 | 0.5 |  |
| A1020 | 1.3 |  |
| A1020 | 2.2 |  |
| A1020 | 3.1 |  |
| B1020 | 0.5 |  |
| B1020 | 1.4 |  |
| D1020 | 0.5 |  |
| D1020 | 1.4 |  |

How do I find cumulative percentage of each group so i get

| F TSI | F ONS | Cum%ONS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1020 | 0.5 | 7.142% |
| A1020 | 1.3 | 25.71% |
| A1020 | 2.2 | 57.13% |
| A1020 | 3.0 | 100% |
| B1020 | 0.5 | 26.315% |
| B1020 | 1.4 | 100% |
| D1020 | 0.5 | 26.3% |
| D1020 | 1.4 | 100% |

```
a = df.groupby(['TSI'])['Final ONS'].cumsum()
b = df.groupby(['TSI'])['Final ONS'].sum()
g = df.groupby(['TSI'])['Final 
ONS'].cumsum(axis=0)/df.groupby(['TSI'])['Final ONS'].sum()
g = pd.DataFrame(g)
g
```

This code gives me nan values

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach:

(i) `groupby` "F_TSI" and find cumsum of "F_ONS" for each group

(ii) `groupby` "F_TSI" and transform the sum of "F_ONS" for each group

(iii) divide (i) by (ii) for the percentages

```
gb_obj = df.groupby('F_TSI')['F_ONS']
df['Cum%ONS'] = gb_obj.cumsum() / gb_obj.transform('sum') * 100
```

Output:

```
   F_TSI  F_ONS     Cum%ONS
0  A1020    0.5    7.042254
1  A1020    1.3   25.352113
2  A1020    2.2   56.338028
3  A1020    3.1  100.000000
4  B1020    0.5   26.315789
5  B1020    1.4  100.000000
6  D1020    0.5   26.315789
7  D1020    1.4  100.000000
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!
Could you please explain what I was doing wrong and why I was getting nan values and why we should use object.transform('sum')

Comment: @DhairyaMody `transform` returns a DataFrame with the same indices as the original object filled with the group sums. In other words the lengths match with the original DataFrame. That's why you can element-wise divide. With `sum`, because it's not a scalar pandas wouldn't know which number corresponds to which group. That's why you get incorrect values.